# Let $(M, d)$ be a metric space and $A\subset M$. Show that $U\subset A$ is open

Tags: general-topology

The entire question is as follows:

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and $A\subset M$.  Consider the metric space $(A,d)$.

Show that a set $U\subset A$ is open in $(A,d)$ if and only if there exists an open set $V$ in $(M,d)$ such that $U = A\cap V$.

I'm struggling on this particular problem and in topology proofs in general.  I'm having a hard time applying the definitions to solve problems/develop proofs.

I'm thinking this has something to do with connected sets. Intuitively, I can tell that, with $V$ open, it would follow that $U$ is open.  Should I proceed by showing the complement of $U$ is closed?  Here's what I have tried:

Let $x_0 \in U$.  Since $V$ is open, $V = int(V)$ and $x_0 \in int(V)$.  I then need to show that $x_0$ is in int(A), but I'm not sure how to do that.

If I consider connectedness, I recall the definition of separate being two open subsets $U, V$ that satisfy:

(a) $U \cap V \cap A = \emptyset$
(b) $A \cap U \neq \emptyset$
(c) $A \cap V \neq \emptyset$
(d) $A \subset U \cup V$

It is my understanding that all of these must be true to be disconnected.  So, since $U \cap V \cap A \neq \emptyset$, A is connected, but how do I prove that U is open here?  The grader has shown in the past that citing the definition is not sufficient.  You must show work.  How do I go from this definition, which appears pretty straightforward, to a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you thought about connected sets, but the solution to that problem is actually much simpler: Let $d$ be the metric given in $M$. Given a subset $X\subseteq M$, a point $x\in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$, let us write the open ball $B^X_\varepsilon(x)=\left\{y\in X:d(x,y)<\varepsilon\right\}$.

Notice that, if $Y\subseteq X$ and $x\in X$, then $B^Y_\varepsilon(x)=B^X_\varepsilon(x)\cap Y$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ *Suppose that $U=A\cap V$ for some $V$ open in $M$. Let us show that $U$ is open in $(A,d)$.*

Let $x_0\in U$. In particular, $x_0\in V$, so there exists $\varepsilon>0$, such that $B^M_\varepsilon(x_0)\subseteq V$. Notice that $B^A_\varepsilon(x_0)=B^M_\varepsilon(x_0)\cap A\subseteq V\cap A=U$.

Thus, for any $x_0\in U$ there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B^A_\varepsilon(x_0)\subseteq U$. This means that $U$ is open in $A$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ *Suppose that $U$ is open in $A$. Letu ss find an $V$ open in $M$ such that $U=A\cap V$.*

This is the hardest diretion to work on. To see the motitation for the proof, reveal the following spoiler:

> Knowing that the result is true, the problem is to give a proper definition of some $V$ for which $U=A\cap V$. In principle, there could be many possibilities for such $V$. However, if $V_1$ and $V_2$ both satisfy $U=A\cap V_1=A\cap V_2$, then their union $V_{1,2}=V_1\cup V_2$ also satisfies this properties, by distributivity:
>  $$A\cap(V_1\cup V_2)=(A\cap V_1)\cup(A\cap V_2)=U\cup U= U$$ Since open sets are closed under unions, our best guess is to try and find the **largest** possible such $V$.

Let $\mathscr{V}$ be the collection of all open sets $W$ in $M$ for which $W\cap A\subseteq U$. Formally,
$$\mathscr{V}=\left\{W\subseteq M: W\text{ is open in }M\text{ and }W\cap A\subseteq U\right\}$$
Let $V$ be the union of all elements of $\mathscr{V}$. Since $V$ is an union of open subsets of $M$, $V$ is open in $M$ itself.

Let us show that $V\cap A=U$. By the definition of $\mathscr{V}$, it's clear that $V\cap A\subseteq U$.

For the oposite inclusion, let $x_0\in U$. Then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B^A_\varepsilon(x_0)\subseteq U$. Then $B^M_\varepsilon(x_0)$ belongs to $\mathscr{V}$, as $B^M_\varepsilon(x_0)$ is an open set in $M$ and
$$B^M_\varepsilon(x_0)\cap A=B^A_\varepsilon(x_0)\subseteq U.$$
Since $V$ is the union of all elements of $\mathscr{V}$, then in particular
$$x_0\in B^M_\varepsilon(x_0)\subseteq V.$$
But we also know that
$$x_0\in U\subseteq A$$.
Putting these two inclusions together yields $x_0\in V\cap A$, just as we wanted.

Therefore, $V\cap A=U$, as we wanted.

Comment: This answer actually flipped the light switch on for me for this whole class.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. In your second to last paragraph, you show $B^A_\varepsilon(x_0)\subseteq V\cap A$, but not $U\subseteq V\cap A$, right?

Answer (score 0):

Notation: 
$$B(x,r)=\{y\in M | d(x,y) < r_x\}
$$

---

1. Assume that $U = A\cap V, V$ open set of $M$, let $x\in U$. As $x\in V$, there is a $r>0$ such as $B(x,r)\subset V$; $$
   \{y\in A | d(x,y) < r\} = A\cap B(x,r)\subset A\cap V=U
   $$
   hence $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $A$, and $U$ is open in $A$.
2. If $U$ is an open set of $A$: for every $x$ there is $r_x$ such as 
   $$\{y\in A | d(x,y) < r_x\}\subset U.
   $$
   Actually, there is even $U = \cup_{x\in U} \{y\in A | d(x,y) < r_x\}$.

   Now consider $V = \cup B(x,r_x)$. This is an open set of $M$ (union of open sets) such as $$U = \bigcup_{x\in U} \{y\in A | d(x,y) < r_x\}
   = \bigcup_{x\in U} A\cap B(x,r_x) = A\cap\bigcup_{x\in U}B(x,r_x) = A\cap V.
   $$

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with connectedness.

Use the fact that a set is open if and only it's it's a union of open balls.

If $U\subseteq A$ is open in $A$, then $U=\bigcup_{i\in I} B_i^A$ and set $V=\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i^M$ of the correspondent balls in M.

Similarly the other direction.